# SQL generated from LINQ not consistent

Tags: c#, linq, plsql, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik Open/Data Access ORM against an ORACLE.

Why do these two statements result in different SQL commands?

**Statement #1**

```
 IQueryable<WITransmits> query = from wiTransmits in uow.DbContext.StatusMessages
            select wiTransmits;

query = query.Where(e=>e.MessageID == id);
```

Results in the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    a."MESSAGE_ID" COL1, 
   -- additional fields
FROM "XFE_REP"."WI_TRANSMITS" a 
WHERE 
    a."MESSAGE_ID" = :p0
```

**Statement #2**

```
 IQueryable<WITransmits> query = from wiTransmits in uow.DbContext.StatusMessages
            select new WITransmits
            {
                MessageID = wiTranmits.MessageID,
                Name = wiTransmits.Name
            };

query = query.Where(e=>e.MessageID == id);
```

Results in the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    a."MESSAGE_ID" COL1, 
   -- additional fields
FROM "XFE_REP"."WI_TRANSMITS" a
```

The query generated with the second statement #2 returns, obviously EVERY record in the table when I only want the one. Millions of records make this prohibitive.

Comment: Looks like a projection is returned as `IEnumerable` by the ORM. What's the type of `query` in both cases after the first statement?

Comment: They are both IQueryable<WITransmits> (updated original post)

Comment: And the concrete types?

Comment: This isn't a PL/SQL question. I think you meant [`sql`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query returns the full object defined, so any additional limitations (like `Where`) can be appended to it before it is actually being run. Therefore the query can be combined as you showed.

The second one returns a new object, which can be whatever type and contain whatever information. Therefore the query is sent to the database as "return everything" and after the objects have been created all but the ones that match the `Where` clause are discarded.

Even though the type were the same in both of them, think of this situation:

```
var query = from wiTransmits in uow.DbContext.StatusMessages
    select new WITransmits
    {
        MessageID = wiTranmits.MessageID * 4 - 2,
        Name = wiTransmits.Name
    };
```

How would you combine the `Where` query now? Sure, you could go through the code inside the new object creation and try to move it outside, but since there can be *anything* it is not feasible. What if the checkup is some lookup function? What if it's not deterministic?

Therefore if you create new objects based on the database objects there will be a border where the objects will be retrieved and then further queries will be done in memory.

Comment: In an ORM like Entity Framework, the whole expression --including `wiTranmits.MessageID * 4 - 2` -- would be translated into SQL, so sorting/filtering by `MessageID` would also show in the query. I think Telerik has a different strategy here.

Comment: Maybe a better examine then is MessageID = LocalFunction(wiTransmits.MessageID),

Answer (score 1):

Telerik Data Access will try to split each query into database-side and client-side (or in-memory LINQ if you prefer it).
Having projection with `select new` is sure trigger that will make everything in your LINQ expression tree after the projection to go to the client side.
Meaning in your second case you have inefficient LINQ query as any filtering is applied in-memory and you have already transported a lot of unnecessary data.
If you want compose LINQ expressions in the way done in case 2, you can append the `Select` clause last or explicitly convert the result to `IEnumerable<T>` to make it obvious that any further processing will be done in-memory.